# Given the prime factors of two natural numbers, is it possible to decide which of the numbers is greater?

Tags: prime-factorization, natural-numbers

When representing two numbers by their numerals in positional notation, e.g. $720$ and $721$, it is easy to decide which of the numbers is greater by comparing their digits from left to right. Alternatively, every natural number can be uniquely identified by its prime factorization. So I'm wondering whether it's possible to decide which number is greater by considering the two prime factorizations (without multiplying the prime factors to get back the original numbers). E.g. $\{2,2,2,2,3,3,5\}$ and $\{7,103\}$.

Comment: What is the application?  Prime factorisation tends to be much harder than multiplication.  Is there a problem you are working on where you start with prime factors?

Comment: @Doug I've actually run into something similar before: wanting to determine if say $p_1 p_2 p_3 \gt p_2^2 p_1$ for example by applying the basic axioms for inequality and algebra, and relying solely on Bertrand's postulate otherwise.

Comment: The answer is certainly no, especially if you want a method less complex than multiplication. But that seems difficult to prove.

Comment: @a_guest Can we use the most basic of the deeper results like: $2p_{n+1} \gt p_n$?  That's Bertrand's.

Comment: @Primegaphomologystonermon, interesting.

Comment: I used this difficulty as an example when comparing the pros and cons of the (usual) positional system of representing integers to the system where integers are given by their prime factorization. The more obvious difficulty with the latter is, of course, addition. +1 for coming up with a nicer example. I used $2^{19}$ and $3^{12}$, i.e. comparing twelve fifths to seven octaves :-)

Comment: Are you says specifally that you know you have $p_1^4p_2^2p^3$ vs $p_4p_{27}$, that is you have the indices.  I suppose you can have some general binding that $p_4p_{27}<4p_5p_{28}$ but one has to be careful as have alot of leeway in $p_k + 2\le p_{k+1} < 2\p_k$.   Still it's worth exploring but .... you are on your own.

Comment: No, this is actually a really good question.  I'm coming up with my best answer right now.  I'm wondering if there is a way to do this _without_ Bertrand's.  There are clearly some rules we can come up with such that $2^a3^b \gt 2^x 3^y$ at least whenever $a \geq x$ and $b \geq y$.

Comment: Probably there is not such a method in general, but, this would be difficult to formalize to get a definitive answer in the form of a theorem.  You'd have to decide exactly what you mean by a method "not multiplying the prime factors". You could have methods that multiply in disguise, e.g. taking logs and adding, but presumably that's not what you have in mind.

Comment: @Doug There is no specific application, I asked this question out of curiosity.

Comment: Given $p_1^{e_1} \cdot p_2^{e_2} \cdot ... \cdot p_m^{e_m}$ and $q_1^{f_1} \cdot q_2^{f_2} \cdot ... \cdot q_n^{f_n}$, the only way we could be sure that the former is less than or equal to the latter is if $m \le n$ and $p_i \le q_i$ and $e_i \le f_i$ for $1 \le i \le m$.

Comment: @JairTaylor Indeed, that requirement seems not precise enough. What I meant is, if there is a way to compare the prime factors (or their ordinals) without doing arithmetic operations on them. I.e. only by using a set of relations for the prime numbers.

Comment: Yes, I think reformulating this problem in terms of just the ordinals is preferable. So in this case, the question would look the way @fleablood put it.

Comment: This comes up when searching for [highly composite numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_composite_number), and superior highly composite numbers.